# Write a SQL query to achieve below result

Tags: sql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to learn SQL using different scenarios. Can someone please help me achieve following result, each column has to be in ascending order.

Table data

```
col1 col2
10    3
20   2
30   1
```

Output should be:

```
10,1 
20,2
30,3
```

another example

Table data

```
col1 col2
10    10
20   9
30   7
```

Output should be:

```
10,7 
20,9
30,10
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about 'how' the output is determined.

Comment: do you want to sort values of col2 based on col1?

Comment: For example: select  col1 from tab order by col1 asc;
Select col2 from tab order by col2 asc;
Now I want combined output of both of  these queries so as to obtain final result as indicated

Answer (score 1):

As we're lucky guessing, let me try:

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 10, 3 from dual union
  3     select 20, 2 from dual union
  4     select 30, 1 from dual
  5    ),
  6  inter as
  7    (select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) rn1,
  8            col2, row_number() over (order by col2) rn2
  9     from test
 10    )
 11  select i1.col1, i2.col2
 12  from inter i1 join inter i2 on i1.rn1 = i2.rn2
 13  order by i1.col1;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
        10          1
        20          2
        30          3

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

THIS ADDRESSES THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

Your question is quite vague and open to multiple interpretations.

Do you want this?

```
select col1, 4 - col2
from t
order by col1;
```

I would guess that you do not.  Your question needs more detail to be helpful.

Comment: That's a totally plausible answer to the OP question. Since they were not specific at all about 'how' the output should be determined, they might end up with a ton of random answers.

Comment: Your query is more specific to data which I have provided, here data in tables can be any numbers. I am looking for a combined result of order by on each column in ascending and merge that result or any other approach to achieve that.